# radio button return false onclick

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have this form here and want each radio buttons not to be able to be checked. I dont want disabled because if one happens to be selected I still want that value to be submitted to the database. This is just a basic example.

When I click on one of them it checks, then does not allow me to click the other one.
I want both buttons not to be able to be checked.

```
 <form action="here.php" method="post"> 
    <input onclick="return false" type="radio"  name="firstone" value="Yes"    /> Yes 
    <input  onclick="return false" type="radio" name="firstone" value="No"   /> No
    <input type="submit"  /> 
    </form>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I dont want to use javascript.

Comment: Why not just add a hidden field with the value if you don't want the user to click on the radio?

Comment: Looking into the hidden field option. Never thought about that Thanks.

Comment: Hell yeah. Thanks Schleis. Been messing with this for awhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to prevent clicking on radio buttons.  You should use a hidden element to contain the values to send with your form.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can imagine you want to have them disabled, but not 'disabled' is because they look ugly when they're disabled.

How about you just change the CSS on the page?

[:disabled CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp)

Comment: The reason I dont want it disabled is when I update my database it doesnt resubmit the fields that are disabled

Comment: Gotcha. My bad. What if you disable them, and then have javascript re-enable right before submission?